# What is the meaning of "award the envoy" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in a chapter named "The Ghat of the only World" which was:

> No one had a greater influence on Shahid's poetry than James Merill; indeed, in the poem in which he most explicitly prefigured his own death, he **awarded the envoy** to Merill: Shahid, hush, this is me, James, The loved ones always leaves.

What is the meaning of "awarded the envoy" in the sentence?

Comment: Please provide the book you are referencing to aid research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Oxford English Dictionary, *envoy, n.1.a*:

> The action of sending forth a poem; hence, the concluding part of a poetical or prose composition; the author's parting words; a dedication, postscript. Now chiefly the short stanza which concludes a poem written in certain archaic metrical forms. arch.

Poets writing in formal verse will sometimes include an envoy (or *envoi* if the original French spelling is used) as a kind of send-off. Traditionally troubadours and medieval poets would use the envoy to address an entity they were seeking to honor, whether actual (a benefactor, a noble, a friend) or abstract (e.g. Hope). ([The Wikipedia page has just a bit more context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envoi).) Post-medieval poets maintained the practice. Note that the usage is archaic, so that this isn't the current fashion for free verse poets, though it may crop up on occasion.

Thus I assume that James Merrill devoted an *envoy* (i.e., he wrote an ending stanza for one of his poems) to Shahid.

Comment: Does that mean it's a bit like dedicating a book to someone?

Answer (score -2):

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/envoy)

> **envoy** (noun)
>
> **1a** : a minister plenipotentiary accredited to a foreign government who ranks between an ambassador and a minister resident
>
> — called also envoy extraordinary
>
> **b** : a person delegated to represent one government in its dealings with another
>
> **2** : messenger, representative

This could imply that the position of envoy was awarded to Merill.

Would this make sense in context?

Comment: You've made a good guess given this dictionary entry, but there's another meaning of envoy: basically it's the conclusion of some poems. It's literally a send-off.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin Thank you for pointing it out, I suggest you make a suitable counter-answer.